# Optimized function to separate arrays into bins

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I am making a function in python to separate two arrays x and y into a predetermined number of bins based on the x array. I have made one algorithm that works, but it is really slow. Here's the code that (apparently) works:

```
def sepbin(x, y, classes_number=100, log_scale=True):
    if log_scale:
        if x[0]<=0:
            print 'Warning: zero value in array about to be log-scaled. Ignoring it.'
            x=x[1:]
            y=y[1:]
        bins=np.logspace(np.log(x[0]), np.log(x[-1]), classes_number+1, base=np.e)
    else:
        bins=np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], classes_number+1)
    ybins=[[] for i in range(classes_number)]
    xbins=[[] for i in range(classes_number)]
    for xx, yy in zip(x,y):
        i=0
        while i<classes_number:
            if ((xx>=bins[i]) and (xx<bins[i+1])):
                ybins[i].append(yy)
                xbins[i].append(xx)
                break
            elif (i==(classes_number-1)) and xx==bins[-1]:
                ybins[i].append(yy)
                xbins[i].append(xx)
                break
            else:
                i+=1
    xsm = np.array(map(np.mean, xbins))
    ysm = np.array(map(np.mean, ybins))
    return xsm, ysm
```

As you can see, I want to make room for both log-scaled and linearly-scaled outputs so I can't assume linearly spaced bins. I am only assuming that the data is organized in crescent or decreasing order (but that's easy to generalize).

The code works well, apparently, but since I am looking to work with very big datasets (100000+ elements) I thought this should be optimized. Is there any way I can use `numpy` or `scipy`here in order to make it faster? It kind of surprised me that I couldn't find a binning function in `numpy`!, so maybe I didn't look right.

Thank you.

Comment: As of 2016 numpy introduced `numpy.digitize()` to get the indices. Will post solution if I have time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of your O(nk) double loop, you can use numpy's indexing to find the elements of `x` and `y` that are in each bin:

```
def sepbin2(x, y, classes_number=100, log_scale=True):
    if log_scale:
        if x[0]<=0:
            print 'Warning: zero value in array about to be log-scaled. Ignoring it.'
            x=x[1:]
            y=y[1:]
        bins=np.logspace(np.log(x[0]), np.log(x[-1]), classes_number+1, base=np.e)
    else:
        bins=np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], classes_number+1)
    # pre-allocate return values
    xsm = np.zeros(classes_number)
    ysm = np.zeros(classes_number)
    # find elements in each bin
    for i in range(classes_number):
        if i == classes_number - 1:
            sel = bins[i] <= x
        else:
            sel = (bins[i] <= x) & (x < bins[i+1])
        xsm[i] = np.mean(x[sel])
        ysm[i] = np.mean(y[sel])
    return xsm, ysm
```

In my testing, this function seems to give exactly the same output as the one you wrote.  I'm using slightly different code to select last bin (I was unsure why you'd written `xx==bins[-1]`).

`sepbin2` is quite a bit faster.  Using 100K datapoints:

```
x = np.random.random((100000,))
x.sort()
y = np.random.random((100000,))
```

we get:

```
In [1]: %timeit sepbin(x, y, classes_number=100)
1 loops, best of 3: 5.21 s per loop
In [2]: %timeit sepbin2(x, y, classes_number=100)
100 loops, best of 3: 18.9 ms per loop
```

Comment: That's pretty smart actually. I considered that possibility (after I had written my code only) but thought it wouldn't make much of a difference so I didn't program it. Guess I was off by some orders of magnitude.